# Vertical drop down menu closes too quick

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I have a simple vertical drop down menu with submenus, but this one cracks my head.
When I click on the submenu-parent (Dropdown Page2) I want the corresponding page to be loaded and the submenu to open.
When I click any item in the submenu I would like to load the corresponding page and keep the submenu open.
When I click either on the submenu-parent or another parent (start or page1) I would like to load the corresponding page and close the submenu.
With the current code the submenu is always closing immediately.

The jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/bj1d17c5/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="test.html">Start</a>
  <a href="test.html">Page1</a>
  <a href="test.html" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown Page2</a>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Page 2.1</a>
    <a href="#">Page 2.2</a>
    <a href="#">Page 2.3</a>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu inside the side navigation.</p>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Some random text..</p>
</div>

<script>
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it very well but, isn't it because you're using href to "test.html"? Try this:
`<a href="#" class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown Page2</a>`

Comment: That works, but I want actually to open test.html when I click Dropdown Page2.